# Alteryx Unknown Variable

Tags: variables, parse-error, alteryx

i have a problem with alteryx. The problem is that although I have Score_Yes column in the input of Score, I get unknown variable error. Could you help me? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Summary tool will only output the grouping variables and aggregate variables selected in its configuration. You probably lost [Score_Yes] at that stage.

Comment: Thanks for response.What should I do in this case ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your intent is, so cannot say.  Based on what I see in the screenshot... could you calculate a new variable [Income] = 0.5*[Score]  before the summary, and then calculate [Sum_Income] with the Summary tool?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below option
1. identify from which table Score_yes is flowing, then convert the value of Score_yes to numeric